# PostgreSql user did not find any relations

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am trying to setup database permissions in the following manner.
1. The postgres user will be the owner of **postgres** and only responsible to create database and roles
2. Create a schema for the database and the make the user **app_root** the schema and table owner
3. Create a user **api_user** that will only have DML access

Here are the commands that I have executed. I do not want the apiuser to have any more privileges than SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and ONLY on the schema disclosures. Both app_root user and api_user should not have any public schema access.

But when I login to the database as api_user, I get a Permission Denied. I am unable to figure out:

1. How to grant the minimum set per permissions to the api_user
2. How to ensure that these permissions hold true for any new tables created
   in future

**Here are the commands that I've used to setup the db, schema, table and users.**

Switch to user postgres and connect to database

```
~$ sudo su postgres
~$ psql
```

Create new user and database

```
-- Create the schema owner
CREATE USER app_root WITH PASSWORD 'approot';
-- Create database
CREATE DATABASE apps;
-- Connect to the apps database
\connect apps;
-- Create new schema for the apps
CREATE SCHEMA apps AUTHORIZATION app_root;
-- Remove ability for all users to do everything in public schema
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
-- Ensure users can list down objects in public schema
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

Disconnect the database and now connect as the app_root user that we created to perform table operations on the database and schema.

```
~$ psql -hlocalhost -Uapp_root -dapps -W
(enter your database user password to login)
-- Create a table for contacts in the apps schema
CREATE TABLE apps.contacts
(
    id serial,
    customer_code text,
    contact_name text,
    contact_email text,
    contact_phone text
);
-- Insert some sample data into the table
INSERT INTO apps.contacts(customer_code, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone) VALUES('apollo', 'John Doe', 'jdoe@apollo.com', '536-847-5857');
INSERT INTO apps.contacts(customer_code, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone) VALUES('apollo', 'David Brown', 'dbrown@apollo.com', '254-457-8452');
INSERT INTO apps.contacts(customer_code, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone) VALUES('ryndall', 'Mary Miller', 'mmiller@ryndall.com', '235-654-7845');
INSERT INTO apps.contacts(customer_code, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone) VALUES('ryndall', 'Tommy Smith', 'tsmith@ryndall.com', '854-965-6514');
```

Connect to the database using postgres user and create a new DB user with only DML (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) privileges.

```
CREATE USER api_user WITH PASSWORD 'apiuser';
\connect apps;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA apps TO api_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant explicitely privileges on schema tables (`usage on schema` is not enough):

For example:

```
grant all privileges on all tables in schema apps to api_user;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see this working partially now. When I execute \d, I do not see any table relations. But when I run a SELECT * FROM tablename, I get the results back. How can I see the table names on \d?

Comment: When I execute \d apps.*   I see the table detail definition, but not the definition similar to \d+ but not what I was expecting. Is there a way to see just table names for all tables like we see in \d?

Comment: Try `\dt apps.*`.

Comment: Thanks @pifor. That worked. And then I researched a bit and set the search_path for the user permanently so I can just do \d which is more intuitive to users. But coming back to the original issue, the suggested solution works. But if I add additional tables, api_user doesn't have permissions. I tried ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA apps GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO api_user; but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Make sure that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ...` has been run as `app_root`: it should work.